# Vagrant box add bento/centos-7 for the VirtualBox provider fails

Tags: vagrant, centos7, bento

I'm trying to add a box using Vagrant with this command

```
vagrant box add bento/centos-7 --provider=VirtualBox
```

but it fails with the following error

```
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'bento/centos-7'
    box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/centos-7
The box you're attempting to add doesn't support the provider
you requested. Please find an alternate box or use an alternate
provider. Double-check your requested provider to verify you didn't
simply misspell it.

If you're adding a box from HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, make sure the box is
released.

Name: bento/centos-7
Address: https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/centos-7
Requested provider: ["VirtualBox"]
```

I'm using Vagrant 2.2.3 from CygWin in a Windows 10 environment

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved ... it was a really stupid mistake about the provider name ... NOT "VirtualBox", BUT "virtualbox" ...

The right command is

```
vagrant box add bento/centos-7 --provider=virtualbox
```